# Laravel cashier-paddle Simple Charge The checkout id issue

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier, paddle

- Cashier Paddle Version: 1.0@beta
- Laravel Version: 7.0
- PHP Version: 7.2.5

I am using cashier-paddle for one of my laravel 7 projects. I'm trying to apply a "one off" charge (Simple Charge) against a customer.  I've followed the official documentation to integrate the package in my project but I am getting this issue "**Simple Charge The checkout id must be a valid checkout id**". Here are the steps that I have already completed.

- Installed the official laravel cashier-paddle package using composer
  require laravel/cashier-paddle
- Published necessary migrations and added the necessary API Keys on my
  env file
- Added the @paddlejs in may master layout blade file and updated the
  VerifyCsrfToken middleware so it except routes paddle/*
- Added the Billable trait to the User model Configured the webhook
  route and controller

  ```
  // Route example
  Route::post('paddle/webhook','WebhookController@handleWebhook')->name('cashier.webhook')
  ```

  ```
  // WebhookController
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Laravel\Paddle\Http\Controllers\WebhookController as CashierController;

  class WebhookController extends CashierController
  {
      public function handleWebhook(Request $request)
      {

          logger('I can reach here!');
      }

      public function handlePaymentSucceeded($payload)
      {

      }
  }
  ```
- Generated the paylink variable using my controller.

  ```
  // paylink variable from controller
  $payLink = auth()->user()->charge(12.99, 'Test Product Title');
  ```
- Finally used the variable on the paddle-button Blade component

  ```
  // Blade file
  <x-paddle-button :url="$payLink" class="px-8 py-4">
      Buy
  </x-paddle-button>
  ```

**Note:** The simple charge is not working but the charge for a specific product is working fine. For example this one auth()->user()->chargeProduct(619859) is working fine.

These are the steps that I have already followed to integrate the paddle simple chare on my laravel application. Hope that information may help you. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong or missed any steps. I will be really very thankful if anyone can help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for visiting the question. After doing some research I've fixed the issue. Everything was fine. Just need to specify the webhook URL in the charge method. I think it was not mentioned in laravel documentation. I'm posting the answer so anyone can get a solution in the future.

```
// paylink variable from controller
$payLink = auth()->user()->charge($total, 'Product Title', [
   'webhook_url' => 'webhook URL here',

]);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I had your same issue, but for me error 404 was fired because I was trying Paddle checkout in a not approved domain. You can approve your domains here https://vendors.paddle.com/checkout-settings or you can try in localhost / 127.0.0.1. Hope this helps!